# Modeling constraint in Arrangements with Forbidden Positions problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Suppose five officials $O_1, O_2, O_3, O_4, O_5$ are to be assigned five different city cars: an Escort, a Lexus, a Nissan, a Taurus, and a Volvo.

- $O_1$ will not drive an Escort or a Nissan;
- $O_2$ will not drive a Taurus;
- $O_3$ will not drive a Lexus or a Volvo;
- $O_4$ will not drive a Lexus; and
- $O_5$ will not drive an Escort or a Nissan.

If a feasible assignment of cars is chosen randomly, what is the probability that

- a) $O_1$ gets the Volvo?
- b) $O_2$ or $O_5$ get the Volvo? (Hint: Model this constraint with an altered board.)

The number of arrangements (sample space) is $5!-8\times 4!+22\times 3!-24\times 2!+8\times 1!= 20$.

I can find the probability of a) $\frac 6{20}$ and b) $\frac {10}{20}$ by listing all $20$ and counting, but I would like to understand how to do it with the given hint. I don't understand how to answer this by modeling the constraint with an altered board. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math on MSE see 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Our chessboard for these constraints is

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 & \text{cars}\\
\text{officials} &
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 & \text{E} & \text{L} & \text{N} & \text{T} & \text{V} \\\hline
O_1&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
O_2&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} & \Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline 
O_3&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}}\\\hline
O_4&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
O_5&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

First of all rearrange rows and columns so that we have $3$ disjunct forbidden subboards

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 & \text{cars}\\
\text{officials} &
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 & \text{E} & \text{N} & \text{L} & \text{V} & \text{T} \\\hline
O_1&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
O_5&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} & \bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline 
O_3&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
O_4&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}}&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
O_2&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}}\\\hline
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

These have a total subboard rook polynomial

$$R(x)=(1+4x+2x^2)(1+3x+x^2)(1+x)=1+8x+22x^2+25x^3+12x^4+2x^5$$

There are therefore

$$a_0=5!-8\cdot 4!+22\cdot 3!-25\cdot 2!+12\cdot 1! -2\cdot 0!=20$$

non-attacking rook placements of $5$ rooks on this board.

Next, in preparation for part a), we calculate the rook polynomial for the reduced board when there is a rook in cell $(O_1,\text{V})$ this removes said row and column since no rooks can be in those.

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 & \text{cars}\\
\text{officials} &
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 & \text{E} & \text{N} & \text{L} & \text{V} & \text{T} \\\hline
O_1&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}&\Large\unicode{x265c}&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
O_5&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} & \bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline 
O_3&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
O_4&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}}&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
O_2&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}}\\\hline
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 & \text{cars}\\
\text{officials} &
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|}
 & \text{E} & \text{N} & \text{L} &  \text{T} \\\hline
O_5&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} & \bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline 
O_3&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
O_4&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}}&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
O_2&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}}\\\hline
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

The rook polynomial for this forbidden subboards is

$$R_1(x)=(1+2x)^2(1+x)=1+5x+8x^2+4x^3$$

There are therefore

$$a_1=4!-5\cdot 3!+8\cdot 2!-4\cdot 1!=6$$

non-attacking rook placements of $4$ rooks on this board.

Next, in preparation for part b), we calculate the rook polynomial for the reduced board when there is a rook in cell $(O_2,\text{V})$ this removes said row and column since no rooks can be in those.

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 & \text{cars}\\
\text{officials} &
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 & \text{E} & \text{N} & \text{L} & \text{V} & \text{T} \\\hline
O_1&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
O_5&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} & \bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline 
O_3&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
O_4&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}}&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
O_2&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\unicode{x265c} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}}\\\hline
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 & \text{cars}\\
\text{officials} &
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|}
 & \text{E} & \text{N} & \text{L} &  \text{T} \\\hline
O_1&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
O_5&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} & \bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline 
O_3&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
O_4&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}}&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

The rook polynomial for this forbidden subboards is

$$R_2(x)=(1+4x+2x^2)(1+2x)=1+6x+10x^2+4x^3$$

There are therefore

$$a_2=4!-6\cdot 3!+10\cdot 2!-4\cdot 1!=4$$

non-attacking rook placements of $4$ rooks on this board.

For part b) we also need to calculate the rook polynomial for the reduced board when there is a rook in cell $(O_5,V)$

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 & \text{cars}\\
\text{officials} &
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 & \text{E} & \text{N} & \text{L} & \text{V} & \text{T} \\\hline
O_1&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
O_5&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} & \bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\unicode{x265c} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline 
O_3&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
O_4&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}}&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
O_2&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}}\\\hline
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 & \text{cars}\\
\text{officials} &
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|}
 & \text{E} & \text{N} & \text{L} &  \text{T} \\\hline
O_1&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} & \bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline 
O_3&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
O_4&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}&\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}}&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}}\\\hline
O_2&\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\Large\phantom{\unicode{x265c}} &\bbox[silver,15px]{\phantom{H}}\\\hline
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

this rook polynomial for the forbidden subboards is

$$R_3(x)=(1+2x)^2(1+x)=1+5x+8x^2+4x^3$$

There are therefore

$$a_3=4!-5\cdot 3!+8\cdot 2!-4\cdot 1!=6$$

non-attacking rook placements of $4$ rooks on this board.

a)

$$\text{probability}=\frac{a_1}{a_0}=\frac{6}{20}$$

b)

$$\text{probability}=\frac{a_2+a_3}{a_0}=\frac{4+6}{20}=\frac{10}{20}$$

You can check these rook polynomials using this [rook polynomial calculator](https://www.bluffton.edu/homepages/facstaff/nesterd/java/rookpolynomials.html).

Note, please check your initial expression for the sample space as it doesn't agree with mine, it seems that the count ($20$) is correct by accident. Unless you are not using rook polynomials, but then you used the word "board" in the question.

Comment: Excellent explanation of the problem, and thank you for pointing out my mistake in the rook polynomial.

Comment: You are welcome Lucy. I know how people just *love* having their mistakes pointed out ;) But it was probably just arithmetic or something minor like that. By the way I did all the chessboards using MathJax so as you can see it is really worthwhile learning the basics of the math input system on mathSE.

Comment: You must have read my mind, I was indeed wondering how you made these boards look so good, rook symbol included. And by the way, I think pointing out mistakes is invaluable in learning, but being a teacher you know that too.

Comment: If you want to see the input I believe if you right-click the maths in any answer you get a list of options, the top one is "Show Math As" --> "TeX Commands" this will display the input. To get the rook symbol I used unicode symbol x265c which can be input as maths with \unicode{x265c}, between dollar signs this gives $\unicode{x265c}$  I also used the \Large command to make it clearer. There are a whole load of chess symbols and plenty of other stuff in unicode. You have a good attitude to learning Lucy, now I'll leave it there before we get told off for chatting.

Comment: @N.Shales - First, thanks for the help; rook polynomials and such have been proving confusing for me. Just a note: you made a sign error in finding $a_0$: you have minus $-12\cdot 1$ instead of the positive, and then $+2\cdot 0!$ instead of the negative. (You still got the right answer somehow - I guess it was mostly relying on OP's answer of $20$ instead of plugging it into Wolfram Alpha or something, which yields $0$.) Just figured I'd point it out. Thanks again. :) Oh and double thanks for the rook polynomial calculator thing!!

Comment: @EeveeTrainer. My pleasure. I'm glad to be of help. I think the reason I still got the right answer is that the + and - confusion is just a typo. I will correct it, thank you and well spotted!